# MySQL native similar to PHP substr_count()

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any function in MySQL that is similar to function `substr_count()` of PHP?
Actually I need to know how many items are in a set (eg. `1,2,3` is 3 items).

In a search, I found nothing that was native to this. So I made a workaround with the methods `LENGTH()` and `REPLACE()`.

```
SELECT LENGTH("1,2,3,4") - LENGTH(REPLACE("1,2,3,4", ",", "")) + 1;
```

But it fail set is empty.
But I can solve that with a simple `IF()`.

So, I'm searching for some more native, like, for instance:

```
SELECT SUBSTR_COUNT(",", "1,2,3,4") + 1;
```

Or, better yet:

```
SELECT LENGTH_OF_SET("1,2,3,4");
```

Some solution guys?

**Edit**

Because of some doubts, I'll try to set some examples:

- `1,2,3` has 3 items: 1, 2 and 3;
- `100,200` has 2 items: 100 and 200;
- `1,2,4,9,16,25` has 6 items: 1, 2, 4, 9, 16 and 25;

Basically, I want the number that is the number of **commas + 1**. I've got this value, but I was wondering if there is a native way to do this, or a less costly than I did.

Comment: Use CHAR_LENGTH instead of LENGTH.

Comment: If you are having this kind of problem then you have chosen a bad data type and/or a bad schema design. I'd recommend you to redesign instead of complicating yourself with this issues.

Comment: @MostyMostacho I have to store some numbers to refer to data of other table. I know that the best method to do it is creating a "table-connector" (user, user-sector, sector). But on my case it'll turn harder to work. How no one data can be removed from this tables, so I not need set a FK between them for this step of project. But I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @DavidRodrigues 100,200 has 3 items how ? and why is 1,2,3 has 3 items also ... Contradiction, please explain ,thanks

Comment: I did exactly the same trick as you did b4 I thought it should be sth better than this (some native func, etc.)... but I didn't find anything better.   I needed it in non JSON field which contains integer-only  array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any native function for that and what you do is OK. But to alleviate some pain and hide complexity in your queries you can create your on function that takes care of `NULL`s, empty strings etc.

Something like this

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION SUBSTR_COUNT
(
  _delimiter VARCHAR(12), 
  _value VARCHAR(255)
) RETURNS INT
RETURN COALESCE(
         CHAR_LENGTH(NULLIF(_value, '')) 
       - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(NULLIF(_value, ''), COALESCE(_delimiter, ','), ''))
       + 1,
       0);
```

And then enjoy it

```sql
SELECT id, SUBSTR_COUNT(',', value_set) number_of_values
  FROM table1;

SELECT id, SUBSTR_COUNT(NULL, value_set) number_of_values
  FROM table1;
```

Sample output:

```
| ID | NUMBER_OF_VALUES |
|----|------------------|
|  1 |                3 |
|  2 |                2 |
|  3 |                6 |
|  4 |                0 |
|  5 |                0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/897de/1)** demo

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick

```
select char_length(REPLACE('1,2,3,4', ',', ''));

or

select char_length(REPLACE("1,2,3,4", ",", ""));
```

> LENGTH() returns the length of the string measured in bytes.
>
> CHAR_LENGTH() returns the length of the string measured in characters.
>
> CHARACTER_LENGTH() is a synonym for CHAR_LENGTH().

```
select char_length(REPLACE('10,2000,3',',','')) from tableName LIMIT 1
```

The Query is working absolutely fine with char_length!

> char length : 7 ( even if with 0 the count is ok )

Comment: Won't that only work up to `9`? i.e. `"9,10"` would give 3 rather than the expected 2.

Comment: @MartyWallace 9 means ?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question. I thought the OP wanted to know how many items there are if you split at `,`.

Comment: @MartyWallace no , i think it would work fine, as replacement is performed on ','

Comment: @FayeqAliKhan is right. I want to do something like `count(split(",", $setData))` so, count the replaced data will count 3 instead of 2 in `9,10`, or will count 6 insteadof 2 in `100,200`.