# MySQL sort by number of occurrences

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I am doing a search in two text fields called `Subject` and `Text` for a specific keyword. To do this I use the `LIKE` statement. I have encountered a problem when trying to sort the results by the number of occurrences.

my search query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (Text LIKE '%Keyword%' OR Subject LIKE '%Keyword%')
```

I tried to add a count() statement and sort it by the number of occurrences, but the count() statement just keep returning the number of rows in my table.

Here is the query with count statement:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(Text LIKE '%Keyword%') AS cnt FROM News WHERE (Text LIKE '%Keyword%' OR Subject LIKE '%Keyword%') ORDER BY cnt
```

What im looking for is something that returns the number of matches on the Subject and Text columns on each row, and then order the result after the highest amount of occurrences of the keyword on each row.

Comment: You want to sort by how many times a keyword is in the text or by how many times the keyword appeared in the table?

Comment: You can use `substr_count` mysql function mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173251/mysql-native-similar-to-php-substr-count)

Comment: I think that a fulltext search ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html ) might be your friend.

Comment: I tried the fulltext search way of doing this, but it seemed like it sorts out common words which exist in more than one of the rows. Since i dont have very long text and some keywords will exist in more than one row and if i understood the fulltext search correctly it focuses on words that are unique to each row, therefore i decided to try and find an other way around. Is this correct or perhaps i did something wrong when trying out the fulltext search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below query can give you the no.of occurrences of string appears in both columns i.e  text and subject and will sort results by the criteria but this will not be a good solution performance wise its better to sort the results in your application code  level

```
SELECT *,
(LENGTH(`Text`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`Text`, 'Keyword', ''))) / LENGTH('Keyword')
+
(LENGTH(`Subject`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`Subject`, 'Keyword', ''))) / LENGTH('Keyword') `occurences`
 FROM 
`Table`
 WHERE (Text LIKE '%Keyword%' OR Subject LIKE '%Keyword%')
ORDER BY `occurences`  DESC
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03926f/1)

Suggested by ***@lserni*** a more cleaner way of calculation of occurrences

```
SELECT *,
(LENGTH(`Text`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`Text`, 'test', ''))) / LENGTH('test') `appears_in_text`,

(LENGTH(`Subject`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`Subject`, 'test', ''))) / LENGTH('test') `appears_in_subject`,

(LENGTH(CONCAT(`Text`,' ',`Subject`)) - LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(`Text`,' ',`Subject`), 'test', ''))) / LENGTH('test') `occurences`
 FROM 
`Table1`
 WHERE (TEXT LIKE '%test%' OR SUBJECT LIKE '%test%')
ORDER BY `occurences`  DESC
```

### [Fiddle Demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03926f/2)

Comment: you need to divide by the length of the keyword to get the right number of occurences

Comment: You could also check whether there's any advantage in using (LENGTH(CONCAT(`Subject`,',',`Text`))-LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(`Text`,',',`Subject`),'Keyword',''))/LENGTH('Keyword') to run a single, albeit longer, replace.

Comment: @lserni thanks for a good note i will try a fiddle with concat also and post in my answer

Comment: The results in fiddle is just how i want it to be. Ill just need a moment to figure out what you're doing in the MySQL part there since i haven't very much experience with MySQL :)

Comment: Figured out how it works now, works like a charm! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

You want `SUM` instead. Count will count how many records have non-null values, which means ALL matches and NON-matches will be counted.

```
SELECT *, SUM(Text LIKE '%Keyword') AS total_matches
...
ORDER BY total_matches
```

SUM() will count up how many boolean true results the LIKE produces, which will be typecast to integers, so you get a result like 1+1+1+0+1 = 4, instead of the 5 non-nulls count.

Comment: I think he wants to know how many times the keyword appears *within a single tuple*. `SUM('So the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' LIKE '%the%')` returns 1, I *think* he'd like something that returned 2.

Comment: Yeah tried this one out and as Iserni said, im looking for something that returns the number of occurrences on each of the searched rows then order them thereafter. I missed that part out in the question, will fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// escape $keyword for mysql
$keyword = strtolower('Keyword');
// now build the query
$query = <<<SQL
    SELECT *,
    ((LENGTH(`Subject`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(`Subject`), '{$keyword}', ''))) / LENGTH('{$keyword}')) AS `CountInSubject`,
    ((LENGTH(`Text`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(LOWER(`Text`), '{$keyword}', ''))) / LENGTH('{$keyword}')) AS `CountInText`
    FROM `News`
    WHERE (`Text` LIKE '%{$keyword}%' OR `Subject` LIKE '%{$keyword}%')
    ORDER BY (`CountInSubject` + `CountInText`) DESC;
SQL;
```

**Returns number of occurrences in each field and sorts by that.**

The `'keyword'` needs to be lower cased for this to work. I don't think it's really fast, performance wise as it needs to lower-case fields and there's no case-insensitive search in MySQL afaik.

You could index each `news` item *(`subject` and `text`)* by words and store in another table with `news_id` and occurrence count and then match against that.