# Multiple keywords search

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting trouble to add the search in my site. I cannot figure out the way to make it done.

I 've a table as follow:

```
TABLE A

id     text
1       Hello there whats up. I'm trying to code.
2       there need to be this code
```

Now I want search using the 
**Keywords** = **hello** **code**

And the results should provide me both the rows because both the rows contains some portion of the keyword as follow:

```
id      text
1       **Hello** there whats up. I'm trying to **code**
2       there need to be this **code**
```

Also the result should provide the row with max number of keywords matched first.

I tried doing this but it only provide me some of my desire results.

```
<?php
   $keyword = 'hello code';
   $exloded = explode(' ', $keyword);
   foreach($exploded as value):
      $sth = $db->query("SELECT * FROM A WHERE `text` LIKE :value");
      $sth->execute(array(':value' => '%'.$value.'%'));
      $rows = $sth->fetchAll();
   endforeach;

   echo $rows;
?>
```

**Updated**

I simply Did this and it worked fine for me. But I want to know whether this is the correct way to get the work done.

```
$keyword = hello code;
$query ="SELECT *, MATCH(`page_content`) AGAINST('$keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score      FROM super_pages WHERE MATCH(`page_content`) AGAINST('$keyword' IN BOOLEAN     MODE) ORDER BY score DESC";
$sth = $this->db->query($query);
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Have you considered FULLTEXT columns?

Comment: I tried full text search but got trouble with that so tried this one  @Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$rows` will have the data where your keyword `code` matches in your table you can rewrite your code to match for both keywords as

```
$keyword = 'hello code';
$exloded = explode(' ', $keyword);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM A ';
$i = 0;
$params = array();
foreach ($exploded as $value):
    if ($i == 0) {
        $query .= ' WHERE `text` LIKE :value_'.$i;
    } else {
        $query .= ' OR `text` LIKE :value_'.$i;
    }
    $params[':value_'.$i] = '%'.$value .'%';
    $i++;
endforeach;
$sth = $db->query($query);
$sth->execute($params);
$rows = $sth->fetchAll();
echo '<pre>';print_r($rows);echo '</pre>';
```

Build your query in loop(over your provided keywords) and assign unique placeholders in query to match for all values

### Edit for full text search

Using full text search you can match exact same phrase with provided keyword,In order to work with full text search you need  an index of type `FULLTEXT`.

```
ALTER TABLE `A` ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `fulltextindex` (`text`);
```

And query will be like

```
$keyword = 'hello code';
$exloded = explode(' ', $keyword);
$where = '';
$i = 0;
$select = array();
$params = array();

foreach ($exploded as $value):
    $select[]= ' MATCH(`text`) AGAINST(:value_'.$i.' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ';
    if ($i == 0) {
        $where  .= ' WHERE MATCH(`text`) AGAINST(:value_'.$i.' IN BOOLEAN MODE)';
    } else {
        $where  .= ' OR MATCH(`text`) AGAINST(:value_'.$i.' IN BOOLEAN MODE)';
    }
    $params[':value_'.$i] =  $value ;
    $i++;
endforeach;

$query ='SELECT *,'. implode( ' + ',$select).' AS score FROM A '.$where.' ORDER BY score DESC';
$sth = $db->query($query);
$sth->execute($params);
$rows = $sth->fetchAll();
echo '<pre>';print_r($rows);echo '</pre>';
```

Above code will produce a query like

```
SELECT *,
MATCH(`text`) AGAINST('hello' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
+ 
MATCH(`text`) AGAINST('code' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
FROM A 
WHERE MATCH(`text`) AGAINST('hello' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR  MATCH(`text`) AGAINST('code' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Alias `score` in above query will have value for each row and its matched score thus you can order your result in descending manner to show the records first which has a highest score.

> Note: You can use Full text search in Myisam but for innodb you have
>   to upgrade your Mysql to 5.6 which supports full text searching in
>   innodb too

Comment: And what can I do to list the row that have the maximum number matched keywords at first. Thank you very much @M Khalid

Comment: @user4094669 In case of using `like` you can do so [`MySQL sort by number of occurrences`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132807/mysql-sort-by-number-of-occurrences/22132942#22132942) but it will be cost effective solution in case of performance ,If you can use full text search then it will be easier one and also performance will be better

Comment: I tried full text search but got trouble with that so tried this one can you Please help me with full text search. @M Khalid

Comment: I simply did the portion above that I've written in the updated portion. Could you please give me the suggestion on that. @M Khalid

Comment: @user4094669 Its different from your original post in the updated part you are matching exactly same `hello code` but it will not match partially like to match rows with `hello` and `code` separately

Comment: @M Khalid I found some where if the the keyword variable $keyword is written within single quote('') then the query will search that as individual i.e. in my case "hello" "code" is that true. Also will there be any issues if I write the query as above.

Comment: @user4094669 you need to add + before your keyword see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282679/mysql-fulltext-search-only-results-that-contain-all-words) and also visit [MySQL Full-Text Search with Multiple words](http://www.vionblog.com/mysql-full-text-search-with-multiple-words/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code:

```
<?php
   $keyword = 'hello code';
   $exloded = explode(' ', $keyword);

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM A WHERE ";


   foreach($exploded as $value):
      $sql .= "text LIKE '" . $value "%' OR ";
   endforeach;

   // remove last 'OR '
   $sql = substr($sql, -3);

   $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


   //................
 ?>
```