# How to search multiple words title in different combinations

Tags: php, mysql

i have job title as like 'Sales and Business Development Manager'.
when i search this word i want results like this:

Condition 1: display full search word job title results as first.

Condition 2: display 3 words combination results as second priority.

Condition 3: Display 2 words combinations results as 3rd priority

How to implement this logic in php mysql. and how to order the result data based on conditions

I tried like this

```
 $str='Sales and Business Development Manager';
    $arr=explode(" ",$str);
    $cnt=count($arr);
    $search1=" where job title like '%$str%'";
    if($cnt>3)
     {
      $word1=$arr[0]." ".$arr[1]." ".$arr[2];
      $word2=$arr[1]." ".$arr[2]." ".$arr[3];
      $word3=$arr[2]." ".$arr[3]." ".$arr[0];
      $word4=$arr[3]." ".$arr[0]." ".$arr[1];
      $word5=$arr[2]." ".$arr[0]." ".$arr[1];
      $word6=$arr[1]." ".$arr[0]." ".$arr[2];
      $search2.=" or job title like '%$word1%" or job title like '%$word2%' or job title like   '%$word3%' or job title like '%$word4%' or job title like '%$word5%';
     }
     $qry=mysql_query("select * from jobs $search1 $search2");
```

I am also using Full text search.
Please tell me how to implement this type of logic. search and order data based on search word.

Comment: Answered in past days may be it can help you [*Mulitple keywords search*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322552/mulitple-keywords-search)

Comment: The good ol' smell of [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I've put some comments inside the sample code I've given.

**Code:**

```
$str='Sales and Business Development Manager';
$arr=explode(" ",$str);
$cnt=count($arr);
$search1=" WHERE job title LIKE '%$str%'"; /* SHOULD FIX THAT job title COLUMN NAME */

$search2="";

  for($x=0;$x<=$cnt;$x++){ /* LOOP THE RESULT OF THE EXPLODE */

    $search2=$search2." OR title LIKE '%".$arr[$x]."%'"; /* PUT THEM ALL TOGETHER IN A SINGLE VARIABLE */

  }

$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobs $search1 $search2");  /* YOUR QUERY */
```

**Comment:**

- Do replace the `job title` column name.